# My Bluesky bot using the atproto package suddenly stopped working. Could anyone solve it?

Tags: python

I've been running a bot account on Bluesky, using the following code with the atproto package, and running it through crond in my VPS.

```
import os
import sys
import glob
import time
import openai
from datetime import datetime
from atproto import Client, models
from random import randint

# API settings
openai.api_key = "..."
bluesky_api = Client('...')
bluesky_user_name = '...'
bluesky_password = '...'
bluesky_api.login(
  bluesky_user_name,
  bluesky_password
)

# Post Image
bluesky_images = []
imgs = glob.glob("/var/www/bsky/img/*")
i = randint(0, len(imgs) - 1) 
file_path = f'{imgs[i]}'
with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
  upload = bluesky_api.com.atproto.repo.upload_blob(f)
  bluesky_images.append(models.AppBskyEmbedImages.Image(alt='CatBot Photo', image=upload.blob))


# Post Body
chat = []
chat.append({"role": "system", "content": "..."})
chat.append({"role": "user", "content": "..."})
response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", messages=chat)
msg = response["choices"][0]["message"]["content"].lstrip()
    
bluesky_embed = models.AppBskyEmbedImages.Main(images=bluesky_images)

bluesky_api.com.atproto.repo.create_record(
    models.ComAtprotoRepoCreateRecord.Data(
        repo=bluesky_api.me.did,
        collection=models.ids.AppBskyFeedPost,
        record=models.AppBskyFeedPost.Main(
            createdAt=datetime.now().isoformat(), text=msg, embed=bluesky_embed
        ),
    )
)
```

However, the program suddenly stopped working since November 7, and I get the error code below every time I run it manually:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Desktop\bsky.py", line 15, in <module>                                                                       
    bluesky_api.login(                                                                                                  
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\atproto\xrpc_client\client\client.py", line 74, in login                                                                                                       
    session = self._get_and_set_session(login, password)                                                                
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                                
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\atproto\xrpc_client\client\client.py", line 40, in _get_and_set_session                                                                                        
    self._set_session(session)                                                                                          
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\atproto\xrpc_client\client\methods_mixin\session.py", line 68, in _set_session                                                                                 
    self._refresh_jwt_payload = get_jwt_payload(session.refresh_jwt)                                                    
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                    
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\atproto\xrpc_client\client\auth.py", line 18, in get_jwt_payload                                                                                               
    return JwtPayload(**plain_payload)                                                                                  
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                                                  
TypeError: JwtPayload.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'aud'
```

*Although the above error code is from a local file, the exactly same error occurs on my VPS, also.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/MarshalX/atproto/issues/181

Comment: This is supposed to have been fixed on 6th of November already. What is your version of `atproto`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two versions of atproto and its dependencies installed simultaneously.

The error was solved by removing all related packages from pip, reinstalling their newest versions, and clearing pip’s cache.